# Elevating my Mac application in XCode

Tags: xcode, swift, elevated-privileges

I have some basic skills in Xcode (Obj-C and Swift) and I want to write a single application for doing some administration stuff on client Macs. (For example: setting the Software Update Server ULR, switching on Remote Administration, showing network traffic etc.) What is the proper way to gain administrator privileges? I'd just like to avoid repeating password prompts. Can/should the whole application be elevated?

I prefer Swift, but cannot find a good tutorial or any up-to-date documentation. As I will be the only person to use this application, the security concerns may be different.

Comment: I can't help with a complete example, but a good place to start is https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002589-SW1. And Merry Christmas!

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I've been there already. My attempts to translate the code examples into Swift were pretty unsuccessful.